# How to remove brackets around each item in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created an error with my list formatting. I have a value of numbers that the list is referring to from a separate text document. It pulls all of the values correctly, and forms it into a list, however the formatting is very 'off'. If I were to have the numbers 55.34, 7.55, and 48.9 from this text document printed into a list, I get an output of `[['55.34'], ['7.55'], ['48.90']]` I want to get rid of these quotes and these brackets around them. The numbers are considered a string, but it is to be converted back to a float later in the program, as I want to add all of these numbers together.

I've tried the `list.remove` command, but it doesn't seem to work. This is a simplified version of what I am trying to work with:

```
with open("history.txt", 'r') as f:
            deposList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]
            deposList = [line.split(',') for line in deposList]
            list = deposList
            print(list)
```

History.txt is the text file. The first iteration of the deposList gets ride of all of the \n formatting that separated the lines in the text document. I then created a list with these outputs and printed it for verification. I want the list to look like this: `[55.34, 7.55, 48.90]`

Comment: side note: don't assign a value to `list`. it's a very important reserved word in python

Comment: Side note #2: if you want numbers, since you have a list of strings, don't forget to convert (float in your case).

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it due to missing 'history.txt' file but it should work.

```py
with open("history.txt", 'r') as f:
    deposList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]
    deposList = [line.split(',') for line in deposList]
    list_ = [item for sublist in deposList for item in sublist]
    print(list_)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your formatting from your data:

```
depos = [['55.34'], ['7.55'], ['48.90']]

values = ', '.join(value[0] for value in depos)

format = '[{values}]'

print(format.format(values=values))
```